# jquery - change body background image and caption on click

Tags: jquery, supersized

Does anyone know of any jQuery plugins that would allow me to change the background image of a website AND a 'caption' on click of an arrow?

I need something similar to Supersized, just without the supersized functionality really.

Comment: [Needs more jQuery (plugins)](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif). But really, as the current answer suggest, jQuery can handle this in about 3 lines of code. A plugin is kind of overkill :)

Comment: The only reason I'm searching for a plugin is because my knowledge of jQuery is limited as I'm very new to it all. I need the background images/captions to change on click of next/prev arrows and just thought that a stripped down version of a supersized-like plugin would help me. Although completely appreciate your help - I'll give it a go.

Comment: Are you trying to get something that is dynamic? That is to say, are you going to have several images and several captions and you want the user to go back/forward, etc? This isn't going to be just one image and one caption, correct? The answer doesn't necessarily address a more complicated use. But it will help you if you only need one action.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry I probably should have been more specific. At the moment - well, at least I did have the Supersized plugin which would transition through an array of images and captions via next/prev arrows. I'd like to do something similar, just without the full screen aspect of it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know of a plugin, but you could just use plain jQuery ...

```
$('#anchor-id').click( function(){

    $('#background-image-id').attr('src','http://fulllink.com/to/image.png');
    $('#caption-id').html('New Caption');

});
```

Comment: `.attr('html',` is an odd way to go about things. Why wouldn't you just use `.text('Content')`. It's a lot simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: You're kinda right. It wasn't an "odd way" though, it was just plain wrong. It should have read `.html('New Caption')` ... which I don't find any more "odd" than `.text('New Caption')` ... just different.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible, but I figured I'd never tried so I didn't want to jump to that conclusion haha

Comment: it seems like what he wants is something more dynamic. For instance, you would add a list of images and captions and the user clicks prev/next or something and goes back and forth between the images and captions. Your answer would be great if he only needed that one action on a click of the arrow, but not if he wants something more scalable - at least with what he says is his limited knowledge of jQuery. I think he can probably use the Supersized plugin to get what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

here's a question. Why can't you just use the supersized plugin?

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Simply the image/caption and arrow to display? What don't you want to happen?

It doesn't look like Supersized has the options to turn some of these off, but ith some simple CSS you can turn off a lot of these excess elements in supersized.

for Instance:

```
#progress-back, #play-button, #slidecounter, #tray-arrow, #slide-list {display: none}
```

So that will turn off all of the elements except the caption. You can style the background of the "control bar `#controls-wrapper {backbground: url(path/to/image.png) repeat-x;}` etc. And you can position the "prev/next" arrows however you like with: `#prevslide` and `#nextslide`

Hope that helps. If that's not what you need, let me know.

**EDIT**

I just saw you comment saying you wanted a slider but not full screen. Try this plugin, it's great and I use it all the time - BX Slider http://bxslider.com/

Let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks- i'll take a look. The issue i was having with supersized is that when adding it to my wordpress site, the site's navigation would stop working - despite the navigation having a higer z-index than supersized. If it wasn't for that issue, which I can't fathom out, I 'd use it :S

Comment: post a link and we can take a look and help you out with it.